# Error while naming rows and columns of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have created a matrix in R and. Now I want to name its rows and columns. I have a vector of names and want to assign those names to the rows and columns of my matrix. but it gives me this error: length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
Here is my code, col is a vector of names.

```
    cor<-matrix( ,nrow=159,ncol=159)
    index<-2
    for(i in 1:nrow(cor)){

          rownames(cor)[i]<-cols[index]
          index<-index+1

    }
```

Comment: What is the type and length/dimension of `cols`?

Comment: `cor` is not a good name since it will overwrite the base function `cor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `cols` is a character vector of length 160, then you don't need a loop, you can just do

```
rownames(cor) <- cols[-1]
```

or if cols is longer than 160, you can do

```
rownames(cor) <- cols[2:160]
```

since you need exactly 159 names for each of the 159 rows in your matrix.